# Eureka. Collapsible Section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, eureka-forms

I'm doing collapsible and expandable section with Eureka in Swift 3. In a header there is a button by tapping on it section has to be collapsed and the next tap on this button will expand the section.

This is my form example

```
    +++ Section(){ section in
        var header = HeaderFooterView<customView>(HeaderFooterProvider.nibFile(name: "customView", bundle: nil))
        header.onSetupView = { view, section in
            view.sec = section
        }
        section.header = header
    }
    <<< TextRow()
    <<< SwitchRow()
```

this is my customView class

```
var isCollapsed: Bool = false
var sec: Section!

@IBAction func hideTapped(_ sender: Any) {
    if isCollapsed {
        print("sec \(sec.count)")
    } else {
        for row in sec.reversed() {
            row.hidden = true
            row.evaluateHidden()
        }
    }
}
```

Hidding works perfect, but **print("sec /(sec.count)")** gives me **sec 0**.
How to get rows that were hidden?
Thanks

**UPD** I find the solution. The answer is here https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka/issues/1031